# "this" invalid scope with Functions

Tags: javascript

I have following function :

```
  function a() {
    var d = {
      foo : "text"
    };
    for(var b in c) {
      if(c.hasOwnProperty(b)) {
        d[b] = function() {
          return c[b].apply(this, arguments);
        };
      }
    }
    return d;
  }

  var c = {
    a : function() { alert(this.foo); },
    b : function() { return this.a(); }
  }

  a().a(); // nothing happens

  // but the following works :
  var c = {
    a : function() { alert(this.foo); }
  }

  a().a(); // output : text
```

I think this happens because of `this` in the `.apply` method. How can I fix this?

Comment: Oh god. Why would you write such a complicated behavior?!

Comment: @Florent just to make life easier....

Comment: function a() will be used like 100 or 1000 times, so I don't want it to contain a lot of big functions, so I am trying to link somehow a().a() to c.a() without creating it each time in a() function. I can't create global functions because a lot of functions may be already defined by javascript.

Comment: @Florent ^^ do you have a translator?!

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript "this" keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because your iterator variable "b" in function "a" is **shared** by each of the closures.

Try this:

```
for(var b in c) {
  if(c.hasOwnProperty(b)) {
    d[b] = function(b) {
      return function() { return c[b].apply(this, arguments); };
    }(b);
  }
}
```

[Here is the working version as a jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/gSJC4/)

Answer (score 0):

a() executes in the global scope. When you call c[b].apply(this, arguments) it also executes in the global scope. The for loop iterates back-to-front, it comes across b first, it executes b in the global scope, which calls a in the global scope, which loops over c, which calls b in the global scope, ...

Result: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: That's not really accurate. The outer "a" returns an object with its own "a" property. Thus, `a().a()` will result in that inner function having the object returned from the first `a()` as its `this` reference.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that myself after posting, but I figured adding another layer of indirection to the answer wasn't helping to clarify things.